# integrating $I=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{ t^{p-1}\ln(t)}{1+t}}dt$, don't get continuity justification for function under integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{ t^{p-1}\ln(t)}{1+t}}dt$ where $p \in[\alpha,\beta]\subset(0,1)$. I understand how to integrate using $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d p}\ B(p,1-p)$. My confusion is when we split the integral to $$ I=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{ t^{p-1}\ln(t)}{1+t}}dt=\int_{0}^{1}{\frac{ t^{p-1}\ln(t)}{1+t}}dt+\int_{1}^{\infty}{\frac{ t^{p-1}\ln(t)}{1+t}}dt$$ and we can prove uniform convergence with Weierstrass but I don't get how we prove continuity at $t=0$ for functions $f(t,p)=\frac{t^{p-1}}{1+t}$ and $f'_p(t,p)=\frac{ t^{p-1}\ln(t)}{1+t}$ on the domain $D_f=[0,\infty)\times[\alpha,\beta]$ so we can justify the switch from differentiation to integral.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to prove continuity you on $t=0$. You need only to find $g$ and $h$ integrable on $(0,1]$ such that:

$$\left|f(t,p)\right|\le g(t)\quad\text{and}\quad \left|\partial_pf(t,p)\right|\le h(t).$$

You can think about taking $h(t) = g(t) = \frac{1}{t^\alpha}.$